# How do I make a list of all possible sums from 2 arrays?

Tags: javascript, ruby, algorithm

For example let's say I have arrays
`a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `b = a`
And the output I expect would be:

> 1 + 1, 1 + 2, 1 + 3 ... 3 + 1, 3 + 2, 3 + 4 ... 6 + 3, 6 + 4, 6 + 5, 6 + 6

I would prefer to make this simple calculation in JS or Ruby, but I don't mind answer in any other language. Can anyone provide me any direction?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself? If so, can you add the code to your question that you have already tried?

Comment: What you're trying to do is called permutations. Good in depth answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript

Comment: @dYale, since the OP wants all possible sums, combinations are sufficient, and even those may have duplicate sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, get unique sums using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var r = new Set();
a.forEach(x => a.forEach(y => r.add(x + y)))

document.write('<pre>' + Array.from(r) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 4, -1, 7, 9]

a.product(b).map { |a,b| a+b }.uniq
  #=> [2, 5, 0, 8, 10, 3, 6, 1, 9, 11, 4, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

The steps:

```
c = a.product(b)
  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 4], [1, -1], [1, 7], [1, 9],
  #    [2, 1], [2, 4], [2, -1], [2, 7], [2, 9],
  #    [3, 1], [3, 4], [3, -1], [3, 7], [3, 9],
  #    [4, 1], [4, 4], [4, -1], [4, 7], [4, 9],
  #    [5, 1], [5, 4], [5, -1], [5, 7], [5, 9],
  #    [6, 1], [6, 4], [6, -1], [6, 7], [6, 9]] 
d = c.map { |a,b| a+b }
  #=> [2, 5, 0, 8, 10,
  #    3, 6, 1, 9, 11,
  #    4, 7, 2, 10, 12,
  #    5, 8, 3, 11, 13,
  #    6, 9, 4, 12, 14,
  #    7, 10, 5, 13, 15] 
d.uniq
  #=> [2, 5, 0, 8, 10, 3, 6, 1, 9, 11, 4, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

Comment: Beat me by 42 seconds :-D

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby:

```ruby
a.product(b).map {|p| p.reduce(:+) }.uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for the iteration over the arrays.

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

The result is without repeat.

```js
function xSums(array) {
    var r = [],
        o = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        array.forEach(function (b) {
            if (!o[a + b]) {
                r.push(b + a);
                o[a + b] = true;
            }
        });
    });
    return r;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(xSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(xSums([3, 7, 42]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.permutation(2).map { |x, y| x + y }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through both arrays, adding the first to the second, and storing the results in a third, eg;

```
var one = [1, 2, 3];
var two = [4, 5, 6];

var three = [];

for(var x = 0; x < one.length; ×++){
  for(var y = 0; y < two.length; y++){
    three.push(one[x] + two[y]);
  }
}
```

This would result in three[0] = 1 + 4, three[1] = 1+ 5, three[2] =1+ 6, three[3] = 2 + 4, three[4] = 2+ 5 etc...

Comment: If `three[] = one[x] + two[y];` is meant to be JavaScript, it's wrong.